# C# - Add two integer variables with a random number

Tags: c#

How can I add the values of 2 integers and combine them and keep counting until 50 using a random number between 1-10

At the moment `int humanRandomScore = random.Next(MIN, MAX);` is just reassigning itself a new random number. How Can I keep adding to it instead of reassigning the value.

If I try an add the random number to the `humanGameScore` variable it gives an error

```
const int raceLength = 50;
int humanGameScore = 0;
Random random = new Random();

while (humanGameScore <= raceLength)
{
       int humanRandomScore = random.Next(MIN, MAX);
       int combinedNumbers = humanRandomScore + humanGameScore;

       Console.WriteLine(combinedNumbers);
       Console.ReadKey();
       Console.Clear();
}
```

Comment: What is the error? > variable it gives an error

Comment: based on the while condition I think you should be doing: `humanGameScore = humanRandomScore + humanGameScore;`. By using `int combinedNumber` you are just ignoring values generated in each loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move its declaration outside of the loop:

```
const int raceLength = 50;
int humanGameScore = 0;
Random random = new Random();    
while (humanGameScore <= raceLength)
{
       humanGameScore += random.Next(MIN, MAX);               
       Console.WriteLine(humanGameScore);
       Console.ReadKey();
       Console.Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to me what you're asking for:

```
const int MIN = 1;
const int MAX = 10;

const int raceLength = 50;
int humanGameScore = 0;
Random random = new Random();

while (humanGameScore <= raceLength)
{
    humanGameScore += random.Next(MIN, MAX + 1);
}

Console.WriteLine(humanGameScore);
Console.ReadKey();
Console.Clear();
```